# Why doesn't my SSIS File System Task recognize my destination path?

Tags: file, ssis, sql-server-2012

I've set up a File System path inside a ForEachFile enumerator in SSIS 2012. I'm iterating over a directory, loading each file, archiving that file, then processing the next file, etc. I've set the Destination folder via an expression that uses a Project Param value, and I get the source file from the variable set in the ForEachFile enumerator. The File System task says it can't find my Destination folder:

[image]

Here's the File System Task:

[image]

And proof that the destination folder exists:

[image]

Why am I getting this error? I'd swear I've used the exact same technique in SSIS 2008 and 2005. This is 2012, but it should work the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DestinationConnection field must contain a reference to a flat file connection. The error is saying that you have no Flat file connection manager with that name.

DestinationConnection should not be a free text field. You should be able to open a drop down in the DestinationConnection field and select or create a connection manager.

You will need to configure your output file path as the ConnectionString property on the file connection manager referenced in the DestinationConnection field.

Comment: Huh. I'd swear at least in previous versions I've specified the UNC for the destination directly in the FS Task.

Comment: Or you simply set `IsDestinationPathVariable` to `true` and then select the variable, which you can then set with the necessary text.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and to resolve it i create a variable and i put something like this in the path.Be carefull you must put double "\ \". 
So the path must be like this:"\ \ \ \ad1hfdalhp001\ \d$\ \data\ \Archive\ \"

Answer (score 0):

Using a UNC is still an option. Similar to as you've done with the Source, on your Destination, set IsDestinationPathVariable = True and then push \server\path into a Variable `User::ArchivePath` or similar.

Otherwise, it is as user3922917 indicates: if IsDestinationPathVariable is false, then you need to use a File Connection manager.

In your comments, you indicate that you're building the UNC path based on an Expression in the File System Task. I find I have a better experience when I build my expressions in SSIS Variables and then simply assign that Variable into the Task's Expression. While this step may seem to provide another layer of maintenance, put a break point on the Task and tell me what the expression evaluates to. And you can't. It's only available to the object to use and you are unable to inspect it so you're left high and dry if your formula is off. Which never happens when you're having to deal with escaping a UNC path

Comment: Thanks @billinkc. The UNC path I was using was being constructed by an Expression in the FS Task. I guess I could have used an Expression or Script task to set a User variable then used that in the FS Task. I though using an expression in the FS Task was simpler. It is, but it doesn't work. I probably used your method in the past which is why I remember it working...